# PHP & MySQL, a php form to Insert to 1 table while having from 2 coulmns from 2 different tables that are foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, record, updating

I am new to PHP, using DreamWeaver.

However, I'm looking for someone to help me finish this.

I have 3 tables in MYSQL that are

#### Championships

- **idChampionships**,
- Name
- Details

#### Users

- **idUsers**
- UserName
- Password

#### participants

- **idparticipants**
- **idChampionships**
- FirstName
- LastName
- DateOfBirth
- NationalRanking
- Photo
- PhoneNumber
- EmailAddress
- **IdUsers**

What i'm trying to do is taking 2 existed ID's in `Championships, Users` and insert them to the participants table on submitting the form to identify which championship he's participating in and who is that user. to avoid duplications.

It appears i have a parsing error that i cannot figure it out, which is indicated in the last line.

Please help!

Here is the code

```
<?php require_once('Connections/ACBSEntrySystem.php'); ?>
   <?php
       if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
         function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 

{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
      case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
      case "long":
      case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
      case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
      case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
      case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
  }
 }

      $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO participants (idparticipants, idChampionships, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, NationalRanking, Photo, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, IdUsers) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['idparticipants'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['idChampionships'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['FirstName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['LastName'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['DateOfBirth'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['NationalRanking'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Photo'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['PhoneNumber'], "double"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['EmailAddress'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['idUsers'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_ACBSEntrySystem, $ACBSEntrySystem);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ACBSEntrySystem) or die(mysql_error());
}

 mysql_select_db($database_ACBSEntrySystem, $ACBSEntrySystem);
 $query_AvailableChampionships = "SELECT idChampionships, Name FROM Championships ORDER BY Name ASC";
 $AvailableChampionships = mysql_query($query_AvailableChampionships, $ACBSEntrySystem) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_AvailableChampionships = mysql_fetch_assoc($AvailableChampionships);
 $totalRows_AvailableChampionships = mysql_num_rows($AvailableChampionships);



 mysql_select_db($database_ACBSEntrySystem, $ACBSEntrySystem);
 $query_ActiveUser = "SELECT idUsers FROM Users";
$ActiveUser = mysql_query($query_ActiveUser, $ACBSEntrySystem) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ActiveUser = mysql_fetch_assoc($ActiveUser);
$totalRows_ActiveUser = mysql_num_rows($ActiveUser);

mysql_select_db($database_ACBSEntrySystem, $ACBSEntrySystem);
$query_InsertingARecord = "SELECT * FROM participants";
$InsertingARecord = mysql_query($query_InsertingARecord, $ACBSEntrySystem) or die(mysql_error());
$row_InsertingARecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($InsertingARecord);
$totalRows_InsertingARecord = mysql_num_rows($InsertingARecord);
?>
```

The form starts from here, in the body of the HTML

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
              <table align="center">
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">IdChampionships:</td>
                  <td><select name="idChampionships">
                    <?php 
do {  
?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_AvailableChampionships['idChampionships']?>" ><?php echo $row_AvailableChampionships['Name']?></option>
                    <?php
} while ($row_AvailableChampionships = mysql_fetch_assoc($AvailableChampionships));
?>
                  </select></td>
                <tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">FirstName:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" size="32"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">LastName:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="LastName" value="" size="32"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">DateOfBirth:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="DateOfBirth" value="" size="32"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">NationalRanking:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="NationalRanking" value="" size="32"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">Photo:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="Photo" value="" size="32"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">PhoneNumber:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" value="" size="32"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">EmailAddress:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="EmailAddress" value="" size="32"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="baseline">
                  <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

A loop for the Users starts here to echo the ***idUser***

```
<input type="hidden" name="idparticipants" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="IdUsers" value="<?php do {echo $row_ActiveUser['idUsers'];while ($row_ActiveUser = mysql_fetch_assoc($ActiveUser));?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
                </form>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        
        <!--==============================footer================================-->
       <?php include("../include/footer.php");?>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    <?php
    mysql_free_result($AvailableChampionships);
    
    mysql_free_result($ActiveUser);
    
    mysql_free_result($InsertingARecord);
    ?>
```

There error am getting is

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/entryform.php on line 191**

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting back?  Have you tried running php -l on your script?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are referring to, but my error is with the last line where the php closing tag. All im getting is parsing error which i might have mistyped something while i was raw coding, but i dont know where exactly

Comment: please, past error here

Comment: There error am getting is

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/entryform.php on line 191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your do-while loop is missing a closing curly brace.

```
`value="<?php do {echo $row_ActiveUser['idUsers'];while ($row_ActiveUser = mysql_fetch_assoc($ActiveUser));?>">`
```

should be

```
value="<?php
do {
    echo $row_ActiveUser['idUsers'];
} while ($row_ActiveUser = mysql_fetch_assoc($ActiveUser));
?>">
```